# Precedence in checkbox list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, logic

I'm attempting to store records in 3 different list in order of their precedence. \

My requirement is as follows:

1. Say I have 10 records rows in the table with 3 checkboxes (Checkbox1, Checkbox2, Checkbox3) on each record.
2. Checkbox1 has the highest and the Checkbox3 has the lowest priority.
3. Use case: If I select all the 3 checkboxes for 1 record, only Checkbox1 will be considered.
4. Use case: If I select Checkbox2 and Checkbox3, only Checkbox2 will be considered.
5. Use case: If I select Checkbox1 and Checkbox3, only Checkbox1 will be considered and hence for all other similar condition.
6. I have attempted and works perfectly on all conditions, **EXCEPT** on unchecking of a higher precedance. Here allRecordList will have all the ids present on the screen.

   ```
      for (var i = 0; i < this.allRecordList.length; i++) {

           if (this.selectedCheckbox1Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id) != -1) {                                
               this.Checkbox1SelectedRecords.push(this.allRecordList[i]);  
               //removing from c2 list
               if (this.selectedCheckbox2Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id)  != -1){
                   this.selectedCheckbox2Ids.splice(this.selectedCheckbox2Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id),1);

               }
               //removing from c3 list
               if (this.selectedCheckbox3Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id)  != -1){
                   this.selectedCheckbox3Ids.splice(this.selectedCheckbox3Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id),1);

               }


           if (this.selectedCheckbox2Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id) != -1 ) {
               this.referralSelectedRecords.push(this.allRecordList[i]);   
               //removing from c3 list
               if (this.selectedCheckbox3Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id)  != -1){
                   this.selectedCheckbox3Ids.splice(this.selectedCheckbox3Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id),1);

               //removing from c1 list 
               if (this.selectedCheckbox1Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id)  != -1){
                   this.selectedCheckbox1Ids.splice(this.selectedCheckbox1Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id),1);
               }                   

           }
           // c3 handle
           if (this.selectedCheckbox3Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id) != -1 ) {
               this.informationSelectedRecords.push(this.allRecordList[i]);
               console.log('Select Selected Info '+this.selectedCheckbox3Ids);
               ////removing from c2 list
               if (this.selectedCheckbox2Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id)  != -1){
                   this.selectedCheckbox2Ids.splice(this.selectedCheckbox2Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id),1);
               }
               //removing from c1 list
               if (this.selectedCheckbox1Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id)  != -1){
                   this.selectedCheckbox1Ids.splice(this.selectedCheckbox1Ids.indexOf(this.allRecordList[i].Id),1);
               }                   
           }

       }
   ```

Is there any efficient way to handle this? I am unable to re-calculate the priority logic.
Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

javascript already has Map which allows to store key,value pair.Maybe you can use Map for mapping every row and its priority something like key as row id  and value as the priority and update value for key based on priority selected. You can find
[Working example on this link](https://jsfiddle.net/m4yv3dg9/75/)

```
function updateMap(rowid, boxid, box) {
if (box.checked) {
 if (testMap.get(rowid) === undefined || testMap.get(rowid) === -1 || testMap.get(rowid) > boxid) {
   testMap.set(rowid, boxid)
 }
} else {
 for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   if (i === 4) {
     testMap.set(rowid, -1)
     break;
   }

   if (document.getElementById("row" + rowid + "box" + i).checked) {
     testMap.set(rowid, i);
     break;
   }

 }
}

}

function logresulty() {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""
testMap.forEach((value, key) => {
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML + " row:" + key + " Priority:" + value + "<br>";
});
}
```